# Streaming RTP audio over Ethernet with avconv

Tags: audio, streaming, vlc, rtp, avconv

I have two laptops connected with a Ethernet cable and I'm trying to transmit an audio stream between them.

The IPs are 192.168.137.93 for the sender and 192.168.137.1 for the receiver. The receiver runs the DHCP server and provides Internet connection for the sender, and connectivity works well.

I'm running this command on the sender(Ubuntu Server) to capture audio from internal mic and send it to the receiver through RTP.

```
 avconv -f alsa -ac 1 -i default:0 -acodec mp2 -b 64k -f rtp rtp://192.168.137.1:8000
```

On the receiver(Windows 10) I open VLC and I try to reproduce

```
 rtp://192.168.137.1:8000
```

but I get no sound.

If I open the network monitor on the receiver I can see that there's incoming traffic, and if I try to stream and play on the same machine (the sender) with

```
 avconv -f alsa -ac 1 -i default:0 -acodec mp2 -b 64k -f rtp rtp://192.168.137.93:8000

 aplay -i rtp://192.168.137.93:8000
```

it works flawlessly!

I can't really figure out where the problem is.

**UPDATE:**

Ok, problem solved. Apparently VLC doesn't like mp2. Switched to `-acodec libmp3lame` and now works!

Next problem: latency. There's something like 1 second of delay between the mic and the receiver's loudspeaker. I think that's a matter of codec, because there's a huge delay even running sender and receiver on the same machine.

What's the lightest codec that fits for low-latency audio transmission?